# update state of an object in react-native - I am not using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-native, setstate

I have a constructor like

```
constructor() {
    this.state = {
                    item_details : {}
                 }
}   

someFunc(next_item_key,next_item_value) {
        //append this next_item_key , next_item_value pair to item_detials
   }
```

I need to add this next_item in someFunc to my state variable item_details..

Example:
   My item_details will look something like this

```
   item_details : {'abc' : 'xyz' , 'a12' : '123' }
```

My next_item will be like

```
  next_item_key = 'qwerty'
  next_item_value = 'pqrs'
```

My resultant item_details should look like

```
 item_details : {'abc' : 'xyz' , 'a12' : '123' , 'qwerty' : 'pqrs' }
```

what should i write in someFunc to get this result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**[] notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) and [**spread operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to achieve that.

Write it like this:

```
someFunc(next_item_key, next_item_value) {

    this.setState(prevState => ({item_details: {
        ...prevState.item_details, 
        [next_item_key]: next_item_value}
    }))

}
```

**Update:**

Calling setState in a loop is not a good idea, better approach will be first do all calculations then update the state value in on shot.

Like this:

```
let data = {};
response.result.variants.forEach((element) => {
    data[element.title]: false;
});

this.setState(prevState => ({in_wishlist: { ...prevState.in_wishlist, ...data }}))
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153871/discussion-between-subha-and-mayank-shukla).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the spread operator to keep your previous state:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ item_details:
    {
        ...prevState.item_details,
        [next_item_key]: next_item_value
    }
}));
```

Comment: Better to use a callback with `prevState` to guarantee a correct state change.

Answer (score 0):

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) should fit your need:

`const newState = Object.assign(this.state.item_details, {[next_item_key]: next_item_value})`

Or using spread operator:

`const newState = {...this.state.itemDetails, [next_item_key]: next_item_value}`